# XSLT - replace text node by identifying patterns using regex

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have x xml like this,

```
<doc>
<p>ABC Number 132, Decimal 321, AAB Double 983 DEF GHI 432 JKL</p>
</doc>
```

what my objective is if 'Number', 'Decimal', 'Double' followed by a space (' ') followed by a number, then that middle space value should be replaced by a * character.

So the output should be,

```
<doc>
    <p>ABC Number*132, Decimal*321, AAB Double*983 DEF GHI 432 JKL</p>
</doc>
```

I have following xsl for this,

```
<xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="text()" regex="(Number/s/d)|(Decimal/s/d)|(Double/s/d)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(1)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Number*'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(2)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Decimal*'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(3)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Double*'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:matching-substring>

            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

But it does not return the correct result..

Any suggestions how can I modify my code to get the correct output?

Comment: What result does it return? Always tell us what's not working.  "It's not working" is insufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue in your regex is that you're trying to match space and digit with `/s` and `/d`.

It should be `\s` and `\d`.

However, even if you fixed this you would still lose the digit because you're not capturing it.

You're also losing the `p` element.

I'd suggest a little simpler regex and adding `xsl:copy` to keep the `p`...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(Number|Decimal|Double)\s(\d)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(regex-group(1),'*',regex-group(2))"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <p>ABC Number*132, Decimal*321, AAB Double*983 DEF GHI 432 JKL</p>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Much simpler and shorter**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(Number|Decimal|Double) (\d+)', '$1*$2')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```